# Let's go [dumping]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, burninate-request

[Dumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dumping)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it doesn't really help tell what is happening. The questions with [dumping] are random.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

If you consider memory dumps or something like that, but there are tags for that. This isn't a garbage disposal site.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not at all

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, there are many types of dumping.

Comment: Well yeah, I think the way to go would be simply just to retag those 13 questions...

Comment: "The questions with [dumping] are random."--They're not *random*. They're just about various meanings of dumping.

Comment: Is [tag:dumping] equivalent to [tag:dump], which actually has a description?

Comment: [dumping] this tag

Comment: Looks like someone has cleaned up the tag, so this question can be marked as status-completed

Comment: @Dijkgraaf YAY, that was a simple burninate-request!

Answer (score 22):

From one of Jeff Atwood's [classic posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/336163):

[image: Image of a crossed out dump truck with the text "No dumping $500 - $500 fine - City Ordinance 66-286]

This tag is clearly garbage and can be hauled away right away!

Comment: From that Atwood post: *"It tells flaggers, and anyone else that cares to look, that toxic waste (aka extremely low quality content that can't be salvaged through any sane amount of editing) is not allowed in our community."* Ah, those were the days...